# Spread arguments with React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm moving towards using TypeScript into my application, and I have come to the point where I need to define this:

```
{ id, label, type, styles, ...props }
```

in a component like this one:

```
const TestComponent = ({ id, label, type, styles, ...props }): React.ReactElement => {};
```

How should I define the `...props` part, knowing that the `id` is a `number`, `label` is a `string`, `type` is a `string`, `styles` is `React.CSSProperties`?

Comment: `props` will be of type `any`

Comment: no, this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Types for component props, you need to declare a type and pass it to the component as a generic. If you want to code it cleaner, you can create a *type.d.ts* file. 
 *You don't need to import the type*

```
import { FC, CssProperties } from 'react';

type Props = {
  id: number
  label: string
  type: string
  styles: CssProperties
  props: any
}

const TestComponent: FC<Props> = ({ id, label, type, styles, ...props }: Props) => {
  return ( ... )
}
```

Comment: Note: The second type passed *Props* is not needed necessarily.